# Rendering low and res/high res images

Tags: edit-mode

Is it possible to render in Blender with reduced low res files and then ask Blender to render the final render with 4k high res files? Low and high res files would be numbered identically but would be located in different folders.

Many thanks

Comment: Could you clarify what you're asking? Do you want to render the same scene low-res, and then when that render is finished have it start rendering high-res?

Comment: Are you talking about video editing in the vse?

Comment: What are you editing? Video? 3D meshes? ..?

Answer (score 2):

You can use compositing to output a Hi-res file and a scaled low-res file
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve that by creating a full copy of the scene and change the scenes render settings for resolution and output path:

[image]

Alternatively just set 4K resolution and lower the resolution slider with a different output directory.