# Editing with proxy images

Tags: edit-mode, video-sequence-editor

Is it possible to edit in Blender with proxies (reduced low res files) and then ask Blender to replace those for the final editing with 4k high res files? Low and high res files would be numbered identically but would be located in different folders.

Thanks

Comment: Is your question about video editing or does it refer to images as textures?

Comment: That's strange... the IDENTICAL question was asked some time ago by Maximo: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/26199/rendering-low-and-res-high-res-images. Looks like a perfect duplicate :)

Comment: @Gonzou I don't think is the same question at all. Seems to me the OP is asking about video editing with proxy files and then have blender relink the edit to some larger files for final render...

Comment: @Christopher I edited your question for clarity, If it's not what you wanted please feel free to roll it back or re-edit.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KZl1xS9Lmvw

Comment: @cegaton I can't see how this isn't a duplicate, it has nearly exactly the same wording as the other question.